# Is the correct configuration assigned to the given pair of geometrical isomers of 1,2-dichlorocyclopropane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I suppose that the configurations assigned are opposite as in the left isomer of 1,2-dichlorocyclopropane, the left chlorine atom is coming out of the plane of the paper while the other is going into the plane of paper. So it must be trans. Am I going wrong wrong somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those drawings are rather confusing.  In the following drawing I've reproduced your "cis" drawing and then below, I've redrawn it more clearly.  We now see that your molecule is actually the "trans" isomer.

[image]

The dark wedge bonds should be either drawn both "up" or both "down".  The same applies to the dashed bonds, they too are either drawn both "up" or both "down".  Your drawing is different, it has one wedge bond "up" and the other "down".  This is confusing and makes interpretation somewhat difficult.  In my redrawn version both dark wedge bonds are "up" and both dashed bonds are "down" making interpretation easier.